# mDriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.driver);

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
    mDriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.driver);
    mCustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customer);
```

Can someone help me...i'm getting **cannot resolve symbol 'driver'** and **cannot resolve symbol 'customer'** for the above. How do i fix that?

Comment: Post your layout code,

Comment: Im completaly new to this...where is the layout code?

Comment: In your res/layout folder.

Comment: Have you added this button in your layout file before doing findViewById?

Comment: clean and build your project

Comment: Which one...the main one or the driver, customer one?

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm a Driver"
        android:id="@+id/Driver"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm a Customer"
        android:id="@+id/Customer"/>

Comment: Java != javascript. Also, you have a captial "D" in one place and lowercase "d" in another. Same with "Customer". Those need to match

Comment: Awesome! It was the capital D and C that were the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="I'm a Driver"
    android:id="@+id/Driver" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I'm a Customer" 
    android:id="@+id/Customer" />
```

In the layout file your ids are: `Driver` & `Customer` but in your code you have given `driver` & `customer`.

Check the below code:

```
mDriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Driver);
mCustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Customer);
```